# iterate over huge text file: read chunks between two reoccurring patterns using python

Tags: python, file-io, bioinformatics

i need to go through a huge (20GB, too large for the memory) text file of a biological sequence DB GeneBank) and extract the same information for each DB entry. and each entry starts with the line `LOCUS XYZ some more text` and ends with the line `//`. as an example:

`LOCUS 123 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//
LOCUS 231 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//
LOCUS 312 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//`

now, is there a way to tell python to iterativeley read the corresponding 3 chunks of that file into some variable var. to be more precise:

iteration 1: var=

`LOCUS 123 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//`

iteration 2: var=

`LOCUS 231 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//`

iteration 3: var=

`LOCUS 312 some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
many lines of some more text
//`

many thanks in advance and all the best for the upcoming holidays

Comment: Do these chunks have a precise number of lines or is there some way of identifying the start or end of a chunk?

Comment: the number of chunks varies (is unknown) and the number of lines per chunk varies too. but each chunk starts with "LOCUS" at the beginning of the first line and is enclosed by a line consisting only of "//".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have the following text file:

```
LOCUS 421 bla bla ba
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Duis eu erat orci. Quisque 
nec augue ultricies, dignissim 
neque id, feugiat risus.
//
LOCUS 421 blabla
Nullam pulvinar quis ante
at condimentum.
//
```

we could do:

```
is_processing = True

pf = open("somefile.txt", "r")

# Handles chunks
while True:
    first_chunk_line = True
    chunk_lines = []

    # Handles one chunk
    while True:
        data_line = pf.readline()

        # detect the end of the file
        if data_line == '':
            is_processing = False
            break

        # Detect first line
        if first_chunk_line:
            if "LOCUS" not in data_line:
                raise Exception("Data file is malformed!")

            first_chunk_line = False
            continue  # don't process the line
        # Detect end of locus / chunk
        if data_line.strip() == "//":
            break

        # if it is neither a first line, and end line nor the end of the file
        # then it must be a chunk line holding precious DNA information
        chunk_lines.append(data_line)

    # end the while loop
    if not is_processing:
        break

    # do something with one chunk lines
    print(chunk_lines)
```

Comment: this one gives an infinite loop and only reads in the first CHUNK_LIMIT=3 lines of the file (repeatedly). i guess because the open command is inside the while loop. also i forgot to mention that the number of chunks is unknown just as the number of lines in the different chunks. i'm also wondering why the code doesn't include the key patterns "LOCUS" (start of chunk) and "//" (end of chunk).

Comment: @user3305567 what do you mean? it does include those.

Comment: @user3305567 not sure what you mean with the `CHUNK_LIMIT` because I removed that an hour ago from my answer.

Comment: forget about the my previous questions in the comment section. your edited version works perfectly! i was also wondering, whether python has some awk-style functionality, like extracting everything from /pattern1/ to /pattern2/. however, this solution is fine too. many thanks!

Comment: @user3305567 well there would be regex, but since you mentioned that the file has 20GB, you actually have to load it in memory to do that kind of matching... but that's too much.